# regex to replace everything after period with nothing

Tags: regex

I want to remove everything comes after " . " with nothing using simple regex on notepad++ It seems to be really simple one. I tried with regex "..*$" but no luck.
Eg: 129.435456
I would like to replace everything after . and get just 129

Comment: Are you only trying to remove decimal parts? Just use `\.\d+` and replace with empty string.

Comment: You need to check **Regular expression** radio button at the bottom to really use a regex in Notepad++ search and replace feature.

Answer (score 4):

Since dot is a regex character (match one character) you need to escape the first dot
:

```
"\..*$"
```

Comment: I tired using it. It's saying unrecognized escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try without quotes in Notepad++ making sure you select "Regular expression" radio button in the bottom. Works great!